# Why am I getting an error that my conditions don't match the schema?

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have this query that works:

```
{
    "TableName": "myTable",
    "IndexName": "gsi1",
    "Limit": 12,
    "KeyConditionExpression": "#pk = :pk",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":pk": "TOS"
    },
    "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
        "#pk": "gsi1_pk"
    }
}
```

I attempted to convert it into one using `KeyConditions` instead of an expression because that makes other things easier. So I changed it to this:

```
{
    "TableName": "myTable",
    "IndexName": "gsi1",
    "Limit": 12,
    "KeyConditions": {
        "gsi1_pk": {
            "ComparisonOperator": "EQ",
            "AttributeValueList": [
                {
                    "S": "TOS"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I have the GSI configured on my table:
[image]

But when I make the request I'm getting this error:

```
ValidationException: One or more parameter values were invalid: Condition parameter type does not match schema type
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error.

- My Partition key for this GSI is a string
- The only attribute I'm querying against is a string
- The name `gsi1_pk` matches the value I'm querying

Did I miss something in converting this query? I don't understand what I should change to resolve the error because it looks accurate to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this aws [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html)

```
This is a legacy parameter. Use KeyConditionExpression instead.
```

```
'KeyConditions' >= 'KeyConditionExpression'
```

Changing your key var in your query should fix this.